# Retrieving multiple attributes in SELECT

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-function

In PL/SQL function, I am trying to write a function with following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Lib_func(id number,dateToday date)
RETURN number IS retVal number(1);

myBorrower number;
myBook number;

BEGIN

SELECT P.book_id INTO myBook, P.request_id INTO myBorrower
    FROM My_requests P
    WHERE P.book_id = book_id AND ROWNUM <=1;

//some if condition which updates value of retVal
RETURN retVal;
END;
/
```

problem is that this results in error when I compile. If I remove the second thing (i.e. P.request_id INTO myBorrower) then error is removed.
Can I not get both things selected in a single query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for selecting multiple variables is :

```
SELECT P.book_id , P.request_id
INTO myBook,myBorrower
FROM My_requests P
WHERE P.book_id = book_id AND ROWNUM <=1;
```

Comment: oh okayy. Thanks a lot!